# PHP Loop If same key then merge value

Tags: php, arrays

Sorry my english is bad, and i want to asking here for duplicate questions with so many answer maybe not in my case, i have an array produced from multiple array $_POST like

```
<input type="checkbox" class="styled" data-controller="company-group" data-action="index" name="checkbox[company-group][index]" value="1" checked=""> 
<input type="checkbox" class="styled" data-controller="company-group" data-action="create" name="checkbox[company-group][create]" value="1" checked=""> 
<input type="checkbox" class="styled" data-controller="company-group" data-action="update" name="checkbox[company-group][update]" value="1" checked=""> 
<input type="checkbox" class="styled" data-controller="company-group" data-action="delete" name="checkbox[company-group][delete]" value="1" checked=""> 

<input type="checkbox" class="styled" data-controller="company-industry" data-action="index" name="checkbox[company-industry][index]" value="1" checked=""> 
<input type="checkbox" class="styled" data-controller="company-industry" data-action="create" name="checkbox[company-industry][create]" value="1" checked=""> 
<input type="checkbox" class="styled" data-controller="company-industry" data-action="update" name="checkbox[company-industry][update]" value="1" checked=""> 
<input type="checkbox" class="styled" data-controller="company-industry" data-action="delete" name="checkbox[company-industry][delete]" value="1" checked="">
```

$_POST['checkbox']

```
checkbox: checkbox%5Bcompany-group%5D%5Bindex%5D=1&checkbox%5Bcompany-group%5D%5Bview%5D=1&checkbox%5Bcompany-group%5D%5Bcreate%5D=1&checkbox%5Bcompany-group%5D%5Bupdate%5D=1&checkbox%5Bcompany-group%5D%5Bdelete%5D=1&checkbox%5Bcompany-industry%5D%5Bindex%5D=1&checkbox%5Bcompany-industry%5D%5Bview%5D=1&checkbox%5Bcompany-industry%5D%5Bcreate%5D=1&checkbox%5Bcompany-industry%5D%5Bupdate%5D=1&checkbox%5Bcompany-industry%5D%5Bdelete%5D=1
```

and i have handle with this code :

```
$asi = urldecode($_POST['checkbox']);
$asu = explode('&', $asi);
$arr = array();
$arr2 = array();

foreach ($asu as $key) 
{
    list ($ass, $iss) = explode('=', $key);
    preg_match_all('/\[(.*?)\]/', $ass, $sue);
    $arr2[] = array_merge_recursive($sue[1]);
}
```

and this my $arr2 result :

print_r()

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => company-group
            [1] => index
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => company-group
            [1] => view
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => company-group
            [1] => create
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => company-group
            [1] => update
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => company-group
            [1] => delete
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => company-industry
            [1] => index
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => company-industry
            [1] => view
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => company-industry
            [1] => create
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => company-industry
            [1] => update
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => company-industry
            [1] => delete
        )
)
```

var_export()

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'company-group',
    1 => 'index',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'company-group',
    1 => 'view',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 'company-group',
    1 => 'create',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => 'company-group',
    1 => 'update',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    0 => 'company-group',
    1 => 'delete',
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    0 => 'company-industry',
    1 => 'index',
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    0 => 'company-industry',
    1 => 'view',
  ),
  7 => 
  array (
    0 => 'company-industry',
    1 => 'create',
  ),
  8 => 
  array (
    0 => 'company-industry',
    1 => 'update',
  ),
  9 => 
  array (
    0 => 'company-industry',
    1 => 'delete',
  ),
)
```

json_encode()

```
[["company-group","index"],["company-group","view"],["company-group","create"],["company-group","update"],["company-group","delete"],["company-industry","index"],["company-industry","view"],["company-industry","create"],["company-industry","update"],["company-industry","delete"]
```

How to merge value on same key while looping,  My desire result is :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [key] => company-group
            [val] => Array (
                        [0] => index,
                        [1] => create,
                        [2] => update,
                        [3] => delete,
            )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [key] => company-industry
            [val] => Array (
                        [0] => index,
                        [1] => create,
                        [2] => update,
                        [3] => delete,
            )
        )
)
```

Thanks for advice !

Comment: Would you possibly be more interested in this easier/simpler process/result? https://3v4l.org/qrA2L  or https://3v4l.org/tiIqL  If so, please edit your question and I'll post this as an answer.

Comment: Why isn't 'view' part of the expected result? Is it just a typo?

Comment: Read the manual more carefully: _Using this function **without the result parameter** is highly DISCOURAGED and DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.2._  ...Look, you are literally asking for advice (your last sentence in the question), I am trying to show you a better way.  In what way is your script benefiting from a 3-level-deep output array.

Comment: What are you doing next with this data?

Comment: Okay, cool.  I can't see any benefit to a 3-level array.  How are you querying this data into your database?  2 rows to be inserted? 1 row? 8 rows? What is the structure like?

Comment: @ady I'm still wondering about these unanswered queries that I made about your question.  I'd like to help you and future researchers realize a professional resolution.  I know this is old, but if you don't mind, let's move this page toward a resolution.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to lump all this checkbox data into a table column as json, then I'll recommend a more condensed array structure before json encoding the data.

`parse_str()` will convert you querystring-formatted data into a desirable associative array of associative arrays (each value being `1`).

From there, overwrite the subarrays to move the keys to values, then generate your json array.

Now your data can be simply INSERTed into your database as a compact, portable string.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/9XCP0))

```
$_POST['checkbox'] = 'checkbox%5Bcompany-group%5D%5Bindex%5D=1&checkbox%5Bcompany-group%5D%5Bview%5D=1&checkbox%5Bcompany-group%5D%5Bcreate%5D=1&checkbox%5Bcompany-group%5D%5Bupdate%5D=1&checkbox%5Bcompany-group%5D%5Bdelete%5D=1&checkbox%5Bcompany-industry%5D%5Bindex%5D=1&checkbox%5Bcompany-industry%5D%5Bview%5D=1&checkbox%5Bcompany-industry%5D%5Bcreate%5D=1&checkbox%5Bcompany-industry%5D%5Bupdate%5D=1&checkbox%5Bcompany-industry%5D%5Bdelete%5D=1';
parse_str($_POST['checkbox'], $output);

var_export($output['checkbox']);
echo "\n---\n";
echo json_encode(array_map('array_keys', $output['checkbox']));
```

Output:

```
array (
  'company-group' => 
  array (
    'index' => '1',
    'view' => '1',
    'create' => '1',
    'update' => '1',
    'delete' => '1',
  ),
  'company-industry' => 
  array (
    'index' => '1',
    'view' => '1',
    'create' => '1',
    'update' => '1',
    'delete' => '1',
  ),
)
---
{"company-group":["index","view","create","update","delete"],"company-industry":["index","view","create","update","delete"]}
```

Comment: @adyoi With my solution you can avoid all that `urldecode()`, `explode()`, `foreach () {list () = explode(); preg_match_all(); array_merge_recursive();}` convolution.  You really shouldn't be using any of that stuff when there is a much more direct alternative.  ...why, oh why, do I care so much?

Answer (score 0):

To only answer your question, how to transform arr2.
You can loop the array and build a new array.
There is most likely a better way with using the post array but my lunch break is over, so I'll leave that to Mickmack.

```
Foreach($arr2 as $sub){
    $new[$sub[0]]["key"] = $sub[0];
    $new[$sub[0]]["val"][] = $sub[1];
}

Var_dump(array_values($new));
```

https://3v4l.org/HKM7S

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `key` as a key you could use actual array keys.

```
foreach ($asu as $key) 
{
    list ($ass, $iss) = explode('=', $key);
    preg_match_all('/\[(.*?)\]/', $ass, $sue);
    $arr2[$key][] = $sue[1];
}
```

Comment: That's because `$key` is an array and arrays cannot be used as array keys.

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer:**

```
$result=[];
foreach ($_POST["checkbox"] as $i=>$checkbox){
    $result[]=["key"=>$i,"val"=>array_keys($checkbox)];
}

echo "<pre>";
var_export($result);
echo "</pre>";


?>
```

if use jquery read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery) to send object, if use text query string convert it : `parse_str($_POST["checkbox"], $array);`

php default behavior is:

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
?>
<form action="test.php" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" class="styled" data-controller="company-group" data-action="index" name="checkbox[company-group][index]" value="1" checked="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="styled" data-controller="company-group" data-action="create" name="checkbox[company-group][create]" value="1" checked="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="styled" data-controller="company-group" data-action="update" name="checkbox[company-group][update]" value="1" checked="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="styled" data-controller="company-group" data-action="delete" name="checkbox[company-group][delete]" value="1" checked="">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="styled" data-controller="company-industry" data-action="index" name="checkbox[company-industry][index]" value="1" checked="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="styled" data-controller="company-industry" data-action="create" name="checkbox[company-industry][create]" value="1" checked="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="styled" data-controller="company-industry" data-action="update" name="checkbox[company-industry][update]" value="1" checked="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="styled" data-controller="company-industry" data-action="delete" name="checkbox[company-industry][delete]" value="1" checked="">
    <input type="submit">
```

result:

```
array(1) {
  ["checkbox"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["company-a"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["index"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["delete"]=>
      string(1) "1"
    }
    ["company-b"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["create"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["update"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["delete"]=>
      string(1) "1"
    }
  }
}
```

for your desire:

```
<?php

$result=[];
foreach ($_POST["checkbox"] as $i=>$checkbox){
    $temp=["key"=>$i];

    foreach ($checkbox as $val_key=>$val){
        $temp["val"][]=$val_key;
    }

    $result[]=$temp;
}

echo "<pre>";
var_export($result);
echo "</pre>";
```

method2:

```
$result=[];
foreach ($_POST["checkbox"] as $i=>$checkbox){
    $result[]=["key"=>$i,"val"=>array_keys($checkbox)];
}

echo "<pre>";
var_export($result);
echo "</pre>";


?>
```

Comment: Yes, this is sensible, but the OP is passing with serialize via ajax.  (this detail was commented earlier but has been deleted)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery

Comment: @adyoi sure object is fastest!!! it is default action ; but if you like string processing use ```parse_str($_POST["checkbox"], $array);``` to convert

Comment: @adyoi , instead of multiple foreach ...> use ```parse_str($_POST["checkbox"], $array);``` to convert ! ```parse_str``` wrote in php Core and run fast....